# mudar imagem de png para jpg com php

Tags: php

Galera montei um script em PHP que realiza o upload de uma foto. O problema e que eu preciso converte ele para jpg e para o tamanha de 280px x 280px.
Alguém sabe como fazer isso? 
Tenho que economizar o maior espaço possível no disco.

Segue meu script, não quero utilizar nenhuma classe pois acho que isso seja bem simples de fazer, prefiro fazer isso direto no meu script que esta bem simples.

Segue:

```
<?php

// Recebe a imagem 
$imagem = $_FILES["imagem"];

// Verifica se tem imagem
if (!empty($imagem)) {

// Obtem o tamaho do arquivo
$tamanho = $imagem['size'];

// Tranforma em array o nome do arquivo
$arrArquivo = explode('.', $imagem['name']);

// Obtem a extensão do arquivo
$fileExtencion = trim($arrArquivo [count($arrArquivo) - 1]);

// Array com as extensões permitidas
$arrExtPermitidas = array('JPG', 'PNG');

// Caso a extensão não for permitida
if (!in_array(strtoupper($fileExtencion), $arrExtPermitidas)) {
    ?>
    <script>
        alert('ATENÇÃO. Formato da imagem não é suportado. Use apenas JPG,PNG.');
        history.back();
    </script>
    <?php

    die;
}

// Verifica se o diretório existe   
if (!is_dir("Arquivos/Produtos")) {
    mkdir("Arquivos/Produtos", 0775, true);
}

// Diretorio dos arquivos
$pasta_dir = "Arquivos/Produtos/";

// Definindo o destino do arquivo
$arquivo_nome = $pasta_dir . 'foto' . '.' . $fileExtencion;

// Faz o upload da imagem
move_uploaded_file($imagem["tmp_name"], $arquivo_nome);

}
```

Comment: Isso só é possível depois de fazer `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: ok, poderia me explicar ou me mandar um exemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você vai precisar de:

- Biblioteca [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) instalada
- [imagecreatefrompng](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)
- [imagesx](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php) e [imagesy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesy.php)
- [imagecreatetruecolor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php)
- [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)
- [imagecopyresized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php)
- [imagedestroy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagedestroy.php)

Depois do move_uploaded_file, verifique se a extensão é PNG. Se for:

```
$imagem = imagecreatefrompng($arquivo_nome); //cria uma imagem PNG a partir do caminho
$w = imagesx($imagem); //largura da imagem original
$h = imagesy($imagem); //altura da imagem original
$temp = imagecreatetruecolor(280, 280); //Cria uma imagem 280x280 vazia
imagecopyresized($temp, $imagem, 0, 0, 0, 0, 280, 280, $w, $h); //Copia a imagem original já redimensionada pra imagem que estava vazia
imagejpeg($temp, $pasta_dir . 'foto' . '.jpg', 90); //Converte e salva como JPG com qualidade 90
//imagino que tu vá colocar algo entre 'foto' e a extensão pra diferenciar os nomes dos arquivos
imagedestroy($imagem);
imagedestroy($temp);
```

Comment: muto bom funcionou, mas toquei que 280px X 280px deixa alguma imagens distorcidas, Tem como eu limitar apenas o width com 280px e o php calculou o height proporcional?

Comment: Tu vai ter que fazer a conta, regra de 3. E preferencialmente bota o 280 em uma constante. Eu só deixei ali direto pra simplificar.

Comment: ok entendi perfeitamente, com com base no seu código eu estou verificando a extensão do arquivo. se for png eu converto ele e apago a foto antiga (png). Como vou redimensionar uma imagem  que já é jpg?

Comment: Tu precisa calcular as dimensões desejadas ainda antes do `$temp = ...`. Depois já faz todo resto do tamanho que tu quer.

Comment: hum ok, obrigado pela ajuda ;)

Answer (score 0):

Como complemento à resposta, sugiro que utilize uma biblioteca que facilite o processo de tratamento de imagens.

A biblioteca GD do PHP, como citado em uma das respostas, é muito boa. Porém creio que se você tiver que fazer uma operação simples repetidas vezes ela se torna cansativa, pois a passagem de parâmetros para a mesma é extensa! (tem função da `gd` que você precisa passar uns nove parâmetros)

Você pode simplificar sua vida, por exemplo, usando a biblioteca `Gregwar\Image`. Eu uso e recomendo.

Para instalar, você usa o `composer`

```
php composer.phar require gregwar/image
```

Depois, basta utilizá-la:

```
use Gregwar\Image\Image;

Image::open($imagem["tmp_name"])
          ->resize(288, 288)
          ->save('nome_de_destino.jpg', 'jpg');
```

Ainda no método `save`, você pode passar um terceiro argumento opcionalmente, que é a qualidade `jpg` que você quer salvar para a imagem.

Como eu disse, dessa forma você tem que fazer "menos esforço", tornando a operação e o código mais simples.